Extreme points of the dual unit ball of a Banach algebra
Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra. Let $f\in A^*$, $\Vert f\Vert=1$ satisfy that there exists a maximal left ideal $L\subset A$ such that $L\subseteq\ker{f}$.

Question: Is $f$ an extreme point of the dual unit ball $A^*_1 = \lbrace f\in A^*: \Vert f\Vert\leq 1\rbrace $? If not, what extra condition do we need for $f$ to be an extreme point of $A^*_1$?

As a footnote, every such $f$ is of the form $f(a) = \gamma(\pi(a)\xi)$ for some irreducible representation $\pi:A\to B(E)$ on a Banach space $E$, $\xi\in E$, $\gamma\in E^*$, and vice versa.

A likely idiotic question, but do we know if this is even true for commutative $A$?

Ah, I’ve only seen the fact that characters are extreme points in the context of abelian $C^\ast$-algebras before. Just out of curiosity, would you mind sharing a reference for a proof of this fact in general unital abelian Banach algebras? Thanks!

@DavidGao I think I have a counterexample to this "fact in general unital abelian Banach algebras" - see below.

@YemonChoi +1 Thank you truly for straightening out my mistake, which is today's profit on my ledger. Thank you also for taking your time to write out a great, convincing answer.

You're welcome, Onur.

I'm going to delete my comment above soon in accordance with the housekeeping practices of MO.

@YemonChoi That’s a fantastic and quite surprising example. Great many thanks!

@DavidGao especially surprising to me - how did I miss that? I should have known that not every character is in the Shilov boundary. Yemon's answer demonstrates this actually.

While I am not an expert on uniform algebra theory, that class of Banach algebras also contains a counterexample.
Let $A$ be the disc algebra: that is, the algebra of all complex-valued functions on the closed unit disc that are continuous on the whole disc and holomorphic on the interior. This is a unital Banach algebra when equipped with pointwise product and the supremum norm.
Let $\varphi(f)=f(0)$; this is a character on $A$. On the other hand, $\varphi$ can be represented by a measure on ${\mathbb T}$, and we will use this to write $\varphi$ as a convex combination of two non-zero functionals in the unit ball of $A$.
In detail: define $\psi_+(f)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(e^{it})\,dt$ and $\psi_{-}(f)= \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\,dt$. Clearly $\psi_{-}$ and $\psi_{+}$ have norm $\leq 1$, and
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left( \psi_+(f) + \psi_{-}(f)\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{it})\,dt = \varphi(f) \quad\hbox{for all $f\in A$.}
$$
To finish: put $g(z)=z$, and observe that $\varphi(g) = 0$,
$$\psi_+(g) = \frac{i}{\pi} \int_0^{\pi} \sin(t)\,dt = \frac{2i}{\pi}\;,$$
and $\psi_{-}(g) = \varphi(g)-\psi_+(g) = -\frac{2i}{\pi}$. This shows that $\psi_{\pm} \neq 0$.

As an aside: exactly the same argument works for $A=\ell^1({\mathbb Z}_+)$ equipped with convolution product (this algebra is sometimes called the analytic Wiener algebra). This suggests to me that "all characters are extreme points of the unit ball of the dual" is the exception among the class of commutative Banach algebras, rather than the usual behaviour. Indeed I now suspect that there should be finite-dimensional commutative semisimple counterexamples, although I have not thought seriously about how to achieve this.

An easy counterexample for the first question: Let $\mathbb{C}^2$ be equipped with the $\ell^\infty$ norm w.r.t. the standard basis. Let $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ be equipped with the associated operator norm, which is, of course, a unital Banach algebra. Then $L = \{\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}: a, b \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is a maximal left ideal. But,
$$\varphi_1(\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}) = c$$
$$\varphi_2(\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}) = d$$
$$\varphi_3(\begin{pmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{pmatrix}) = \frac{1}{2}(c + d)$$
are distinct linear functionals of norm $1$, and whose kernels all contain $L$. However, $\varphi_3 = \frac{1}{2}(\varphi_1 + \varphi_2)$.

Thank you for your reply, this is a step forward imho. In the general context of the OP, we can say every such $f$ is of the form $f(a) = g(\pi_L(a)(1+L))$ where $\pi_L:A\to B(A/L)$ def'd by $\pi_L(a)(x+L) = ax+L$, $g\in(A/L)^$. If $g$ is not an extreme point of the unit ball of $(A/L)^$ (as in the example you've given), then $f$ is not an extreme point of $A_1^$. I wonder if "$g$ is an extreme point of $(A/L)^_1$" is sufficient - but I actually doubt it is

@OnurOktay I doubt that as well. One likely needs some conditions on how left ideals “decompose” into maximal left ideals, or something of that sort.

I cannot see what you have in mind; I'd definitely would like to learn if you'd like to take time to tell.

@OnurOktay My idea at first was something like the following: you can actually retrieve $L$ from $f$ by defining, for each linear functional $f$, an associated left ideal $L_f = {a \in A: f(ba) = 0, \forall b \in A}$. One easily checks this is the largest left ideal contained in $\ker(f)$, so $L_f = L$ in case $\ker(f)$ contains a maximal left ideal $L$. I was then wondering if one can obtain, from $f = \frac{1}{2}(g + h)$, some kind of relations between $L_f$, $L_g$, and $L_h$. The only thing that is immediately clear is that $L_g \cap L_h \subset L_f$. I was then wondering if this implies…

@OnurOktay … at least one of $L_g$ and $L_h$ is contained in $L_f$, and if each linear functional can be effectively decomposed as some kind of integrals over the space of maximal left ideals (or perhaps some larger class of left ideals) and then, with $|g|, |h| = 1$, if the weights of these integrals are not concentrated at $L_f$, then $f = \frac{1}{2}(g + h)$ cannot have norm $1$. So then perhaps something like this can force $L_g = L_h = L_f$, effectively reducing the question to the unit ball of $(A/L)^\ast$. (Admittedly though, this feels like asking too much. I wouldn’t be surprised…

@OnurOktay … if it is known this can’t work, and I’m simply unaware of the relevant results.)

I value & thank you for generously sharing your intuition with me.
Honestly, I haven't seen the kind of decomposition or integral arguments in the general context of non-commutative Banach algebras before. Closest I can think of are related to the Shilov boundary for the commutative algebras (as a sampler for what I mean https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0264?tify=%7B%22view%22:%22info%22,%22pages%22:%5B183%5D%7D) , and/or the Plancherel measure for certain algebras in Harmonic analysis.

It would be really helpful if you solidify your arguments in a rigorous answer for non-experts (=me) who cannot see what is beyond these. Besides, there are serious referees in MO who are very detailed & can fry folks like fish for using "something like" arguments (and rightfully so).

If I may, what's your intuition (the same question) for the Banach algebras $B(E)$ on a Banach space $E$? Imho this may be related to an earlier question of yours about the isometries of $B(E)$ spaces.

@OnurOktay I mean, that’s exactly why I didn’t write those as an answer. They hardly constitute an argument for any specific thing, just vague intuition. I’m not an expert in Banach algebras. I’m a von Neumann algebraist by training, as mentioned both in my profile and last question, and unfortunately von Neumann algebras have a basically trivial ideal theory and left/right module theory. So these are really just intuition, vague ideas that I got in analogy with my limited knowledge of ideal and representation theory of $C^\ast$-algebras. I mean, I’m already commenting about my lack of…

@OnurOktay … knowledge regarding the fact you mentioned about characters being the extreme points of dual unit balls for general unital abelian Banach algebras, and I don’t even know the definitions of what you just mentioned, Shilov boundaries and Plancherel measures. So yeah, I really can’t formalize those things as a rigorous answer. The only things that are rigorous in my comments are the definition of $L_f$, that it is the largest left ideal contained in $\ker(f)$, and that $L_g \cap L_h \subset L_f$ if $f = \frac{1}{2}(g + h)$. For anything more, it might be better for you to ask…

@OnurOktay … an actual expert in the field. Perhaps they have some ideas of their own regarding this, or at least they might be able to judge my idea as either being reasonable or complete nonsense. I can rigorously construct counterexamples like the one in my answer, since I know the relevant definitions, but conjuring up reasonable additional assumptions to ensure your result holds, in a field that’s not really my own, is really beyond me.

@OnurOktay For $B(E)$, if you just want intuition my understanding is that it has a nicer ideal structure. I think left ideals correspond to subspaces of $E$ (the intersection of kernels of all elements of a left ideal) and classes of operators (closure of finite rank and compact, probably?). This does seem to mean that there is a reasonable decomposition, since the kernel space of any left ideal can be constructed from intersecting co-dimension $1$ subspaces, and maximal left ideals are all operators (equivalently all finite-rank operators) with kernel containing a co-dimension $1$ subspace.

David, even though it doesn't rigorously solve a problem, talking about your intuition is a great conversation starter. A correct intuition is the first step to solve hard problems rigorously. I can go on and quote Einstein or some other big shot about virtues of correct intuition, but I better stop here.. It's not up to me to say this but you're a great mathematician already - what you contribute to MO alone reflect this "fact" (and reading from your profile that you're PhD student, you'll become greater in time).

There are similarities and huge differences between von Neumann algebras & algebras of operators on a Banach space. Overruling similarities as nonsense by pointing at the differences is (at best) plain wrong, and vice versa. It should be expected that farther away of the properties of a Banach space $E$ from Hilbert space, the bigger differences one would observe between vN algebras and (say) B(E).

Going back to the ideal $L_f$, this is the counterpart of $N={x\in B : f(x^x)=0}$ for a unital positive linear functional on a $C^$-algebra, with which you get GNS representations. The relationship between $f$, $L_f$ and the left regular representation $\pi:A\to B(A/L_f)$ actually parallels this. Compactness, weak compactness, etc. of $\pi$ can be equivalently described in terms of $f$ and/or $L_f$. It is well known, and can be found in Banach algebra textbooks, for example, Duncan's or Palmer's books on Banach algebras.

For the ideal structure of $B(E)$; even for $E=C(K)$ or $E=L^p$, $p\neq 2$, the ideal structure of $B(E)$ can be quite different from that of $B(\ell^2)$. For example: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00208-019-01934-0.

Asking for opinions of the experts is one of the purposes of MO, isn't it? Perhaps another purpose is to get to hear the opinions of experts in near-by fields. So, thanks again for your response, your insight, and for the friendly chit-chat on the side.

@OnurOktay Thank you for the references and your kind words. I agree with what you said regarding the usefulness of intuition, but in this case, with my intuition already laid down here, it does seem to me that the only way forward is to consult experts in the field to see if it actually works. Glad and honored you found my response to be insightful, though.

@OnurOktay Yeah, I defined $L_f$ with the $C^\ast$-algebra version in mind. In case of a $C^\ast$-algebra, $L_f$ is just the left ideal ${a \in A: |f|(a^\ast a) = 0}$. I wasn't aware that this has been considered, but I'm certainly not surprised.

@OnurOktay Thank you for the references again. And I just realized I talked about $B(E)$ completely the other way around. The operators with kernels containing a co-dimension $1$ subspace are the minimal left ideals, not maximal ones. I was still thinking about one of my previous answers regarding minimal left/right ideals. The maximal left ideals should have been the sets of operators with kernels containing a fixed $1$-d subspace or something of the sort?

We're experiencing a gentilezza overflow that is hard to find in academia recently. By the way, this paper contains the answer to your inquiry (Theorem 1.1) https://doi.org/10.4064/sm218-3-3

@OnurOktay Thanks for the reference! I guess I’m not exactly correct, but nearly so then.

Inspired by @YemonChoi 's wonderful counterexample, here are two finite-dimensional commutative counterexamples:

$\mathbb{C}1 \oplus \mathbb{C}x$ with the $\ell^1$ norm, where $1$ is the unity and $x$ is s.t. $x^2 = 0$. Then, $\phi(a1 + bx) = a$ is a norm-one character, but $\psi_+(a1 + bx) = a + b$ and $\psi_−(a1 + bx) = a - b$ both have norm $1$, and $\phi = \frac{1}{2}(\psi_+ + \psi_−)$. This example is not semisimple.
$\mathbb{C}1 \oplus \mathbb{C}p$ with the $\ell^1$ norm, where $1$ is the unity, and $p$ is an idempotent. Then $\phi(a1 + bp) = a$ is a norm-one character, but $\psi_+(a1 + bp) = a + b$ and $\psi_−(a1 + bp) = a − b$ both have norm $1$, and $\phi = \frac{1}{2}(\psi_+ + \psi_−)$. This example is semisimple, since the algebra is just isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^2$ (with pointwise operations).

Both are among the smallest counterexamples, as any point on the dual unit sphere is an extreme point when the algebra is one-dimensional.
